# How to conditionally compute difference in column values between rows in R?

Tags: r

I have the following data set

(this is just sample, actual data set runs into rows)

Image of the data set in also attached in the snapshot
[Dataset snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JA3Fm.jpg)

```
User    Time    Flag    TimeDifference     Expected o/p (Seconds)
A   11:39:30    1       
A   11:37:53    1       
A   20:44:19    1       
A   22:58:42    2   Calculate time difference?  8063
A   23:01:54    1   Calculate time difference?  192
B   23:03:00    1       
B   23:03:33    1       
B   23:03:53    1       
B   15:00:42    3   Calculate time difference   28991
B   19:35:31    2   Calculate time difference   16489
B   19:35:34    1   Calculate time difference   3
C   10:19:06    1       
C   10:59:50    1       
C   10:59:50    1       
C   12:16:36    1       
C   12:16:36    1
```

I need to calculate for each user

- the time difference (in seconds) between rows whenever there is a 'Flag change' and store it in a new column called 'Time difference'
- i.e. whenever flag changes from 1 to 2 , or 2 to 3 , or 2 to 1, or 3 to 1 , I need to compute time difference the time column between the current row and preceding row when flag change in encountered.
- I have time in hh:mm:ss format.
  Is there any for-loop function I can apply here?

Help appreciated.

Comment: I think you have some inconsistencies. For group A, you calculate difference for when it goes from `2-1`. In group B you calculate difference for `1-3-2`...(i.e. why not `1-3-2-1` for B group or `1-2-1` for A).

Comment: Actually..for Group A, when it goes from 1 to 2 , it will calculate the difference and store it corresponding to 2, when it goes from 2 to 1 , it will store it corresponding to 1, i.e. you are going from 1 to 2 & 2 to 1 the difference is computed twice. Similarly in Groupd B its from 1-3-2-1 transition happends 3 times, hence time diff will be computed 3 times.. the diff can be stored corresponding to the transitioned value.

Comment: Ok. Can you also add the expected output please. That will clarify even more

Comment: @Sotos I have updated the expected output for your reference..thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do that is to turn your time variable into POSIXlt time object, calculate the time difference (for all rows) against a shifted time variable. Then use your `flag` variable to `NA` the ones you dont want. The important part is you need to diff the `flag` variable so you know when your flag has changed

I'm laying out all the steps here, but theres probably a quicker way to do it:

```
# Create the data
flag <- c(1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,3,2,1,1,1,1,1,1)
time <- c('11:39:30','11:37:53','20:44:19','22:58:42','23:01:54',
          '23:03:00','23:03:33','23:03:53','15:00:42','19:35:31',
          '19:35:34','10:19:06','10:59:50','10:59:50','12:16:36',
          '12:16:36')

# Shift the time
time_shift <- c(NA,time[1:length(time)-1])

# Turn into POSIXlt objects
time <- strptime(time, format='%H:%M:%S')
time_shift <- strptime(time_shift, format='%H:%M:%S')

data <- data.frame(time, time_shift, flag)

# Calculate diffs
data$time_diff <- as.numeric(abs(difftime(data$time, data$time_shift, units=('secs'))))
data$flag_diff <- c(NA,abs(diff(data$flag)))

# Set non 'flag change' diffs to NA
data$time_diff[data$flag_diff == 0] <- NA
```

You'll probably want to remove the useless columns and convert `time` back into your original representation, which you can do with:

```
data$time <- format(data$time, "%H:%M:%S")
data <- data[c('time', 'flag', 'time_diff')]
```

That will result in a dataframe that looks like this:

```
       time flag time_diff
1  11:39:30    1        NA
2  11:37:53    1        NA
3  20:44:19    1        NA
4  22:58:42    2      8063
5  23:01:54    1       192
6  23:03:00    1        NA
7  23:03:33    1        NA
8  23:03:53    1        NA
9  15:00:42    3     28991
10 19:35:31    2     16489
11 19:35:34    1         3
12 10:19:06    1        NA
13 10:59:50    1        NA
14 10:59:50    1        NA
15 12:16:36    1        NA
16 12:16:36    1        NA
```

Comment: ..thanks will try this out...actuallly i had just put the sample for represntation sakes..actually  I have another dataset which has flags as alaphanumeric ...i.e instead of 2 its 2A , 3 is 3A, and 1 is 1A.. I can replace the alphanumeric by muneric and try ur solution...but lets see if I can find a quick way as suggested by you

Comment: yeah you wont be able to do the diff with alphanumeric. But if the letters dont matter you can always just strip them out and proceed with numbers. Next time, include the alphanumeric issue in the question because that changes a lot. Overall, at the very least this is faster than using `for` loop

Answer (score 0):

Some preprocessing may be required earlier:

```
df$Time<-strptime(x = df$Time,format = "%H:%M:%S")
df$Time<-strftime(x = df$Time,format = "%H:%M:%S")
df$Time<-as.POSIXct(df$Time)

sol<-function(d){
    Time_difference<-numeric(nrow(d))
    ind<-which(diff(d$Flag)!=0)+1

    #calculate differences in time where change in Flag was detected
    Time_difference[ind]<-abs(difftime(time1 = d$Time[ind],time2 = 
    d$Time[(ind-1)], units = "secs"))
    d$Time_Difference<-Time_difference
    return(d)
   }
```

Now using the `plyr` package and `ddply` function, which follow the split-apply-combine principle. It will take a data frame(d) and split it by a variable("User" in this case), **apply** a function(`sol` in this case) to that subset of data.frame and then recombine it to the original data.frame(d).

```
ddply(.data = df,.variables = "User",.fun = sol)

#    User     Time  Flag Time_Difference
#1     A  11:39:30    1               0
#2     A  11:37:53    1               0
#3     A  20:44:19    1               0
#4     A  22:58:42    2            8063
#5     A  23:01:54    1             192
#6     B  23:03:00    1               0
#7     B  23:03:33    1               0
#8     B  23:03:53    1               0
#9     B  15:00:42    3           28991
#10    B  19:35:31    2           16489
#11    B  19:35:34    1               3
#12    C  10:19:06    1               0
#13    C  10:59:50    1               0 
#14    C  10:59:50    1               0
#15    C  12:16:36    1               0
#16    C  12:16:36    1               0
```